# Configuration error: Create Project Web App Instances

Tags: 2010, service-application, health-analyzer

On a new SP 2010 installation, the health analyzer notifies of an error

[image]

Going inside, it declares of a configuration error  in PsiService

[image]

Error detailed as:

> Following service applications do not have any Project Web App instances: 
>   Project Server Service App

[image]

According to the error - I do not have a Web App in the service, but when looking at the service - there is a web app - and in `provisioned` state

[image]

**Q: What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Have you defined a Project Server, but it isn't set up yet?